# DI in an existing middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, middleware

I have the following interface and class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IExceptionManager, ExceptionManager>();
    ...
}
```

Now how do I inject IExceptionManager in Asp.net Core ExceptionHandler middleware ?

```
 app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
            {
                var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

               //how to define myExceptionManager as IExceptionManager
                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(myExceptionManager.Manage(exception));
            }));
```

Comment: You _could_ use `context.RequestServices` to create it on every call, but as it's a singleton you're probably better off creating a seperate class for your middleware and injecting it into the constructor of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` argument in [UseExceptionHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.exceptionhandlerextensions.useexceptionhandler?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_ExceptionHandlerExtensions_UseExceptionHandler_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder__) is an [IApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.iapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You can use the [ApplicationServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.iapplicationbuilder.applicationservices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder_ApplicationServices) property to retrieve services, eg:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
{
    var myExceptionManager =a.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService< IExceptionManager>();
                
    var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

    //how to define myExceptionManager as IExceptionManager
    await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(myExceptionManager.Manage(exception));
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  . I wonder why it does not hit this function when I send an object with invalid validation. and I receive the following error in client without the Run function being exceuted : {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-f7bdad2ec3c0424f8fdf10f5a389d085-6e8c1713f1ce8147-00","errors":{"Name":["The field Name is required"]}}

Comment: I added another question  would you please answer it too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344945/useexceptionhandler-is-not-working-with-validation-errors